# Laravel sub-domain routing set global para for route() helper

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, wildcard-subdomain

I have setup sub-domain routing on my app (using Laravel 5.4) with the following `web.php` route:

```
Route::domain('{company}.myapp.localhost')->group(function () {
  // Locations
  Route::resource('/locations' , 'LocationController');

  // Services
  Route::resource('/services' , 'ServiceController');
});
```

However as my `show` and `edit` endpoints require an ID to be passed, using a normal `route('services.show')` helper results in an `ErrorException` stating `Missing required parameters for [Route: services.create] [URI: services/create].`

I appreciate this is necessary, but as the `company` is associated to the user on login (and is in the sub-domain) I don't want to be passing this for every view. I want to set this at a global level.

To avoid repeated queries, I thought about storing this in the session as so (in the :

```
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    $current_company = $user->companies->first();
    $company         = [
        'id'           => $current_company->id,
        'name'         => $current_company->name,
        'display_name' => $current_company->display_name
    ];
    $request->session()->put('company', $company);
}
```

Which is fine, but I wonder if I can pass this to the route as a middleware or something. What's be best solution here?

Comment: Why not pass the parameter?https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer

Comment: I'm aware I need to pass the parameter, I'm just not sure the best implementation to do this globally. Saving it to the session makes this retrievable within a controller but as I'll need that param everywhere it feels like there should be a better way to do this so it's already configured rather than having to redeclare it in each controller.

Comment: I'm relatively new to Laravel so I'm not certain on the best practices....

Answer (score 0):

Recommendation: remove the slash before the resource name.
The `resource` method will produce the following URIs:

```
/services/{service}
```

So, you should define your routes like this:

```
Route::domain('{company}.myapp.localhost')->group(function () {
    // Locations
    Route::resource('locations' , 'LocationController');

    // Services
    Route::resource('services' , 'ServiceController', ['only' => ['index', 'store']]);
    Route::get('services');
});
```

Comment: This still yields the same exception error... I still need to set the second param (called whatever) for the `route()` helper... it seems to need this to populate the `{company}` wildcard in the domain route, which makes sense. 

I'm looking to set this at login (as detailed in my question) and pass it globally. to avoid having to do something like this for every link: `{{ route('locations.index', Session::get('company')['name']) }}`

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this exact issue today, I poked around in the source and found a `defaults` method on the url generator that allows you to set global default route parameters like so:

`app('url')->defaults(['yourGlobalRouteParameter' => $value]);`

This will merge in whatever value(s) you specify into the global default parameters for the route url generator to use.